# How do I insert a value to a list which is already in a list?

Tags: python

I want to create a list, which does not already exist. So, i want to use the insert function to insert "0" as the new element in that list.

The problem ist that I don't know how to access the index of the element position which is in a  nested list.

I have tried to resolve my problem using : `matrix_result[i1].insert(i2, 0)`

but it does not help me and the programm gives an error because of this line.
Full code:

```
matrix1 = [[1, 5], [6, 4]]
matrix2 = [[3, 2], [7, 8]]
matrix_result = []


def add(p1, p2):
    global matrix_result

    for i1 in range(0, len(p1)):
        matrix_result.insert(i1,0)
        for i2 in range(0, len(p1[i1])):
            matrix_result[i1].insert(i2, 0)
            matrix_result[i1][i2] = p1[i1][i2] + p2[i1][i2]
    return matrix_result


print(add(matrix1, matrix2))
```

Expected result: the matrix_result has exact many elements as there are in matrix1 but all with the value 0

actual result: error because of the statement : `matrix_result[i1].insert(i2, 0)`

Comment: What's the exact error? And do you want to add the lists or set them to 0?

Comment: Please provide an expected output

Comment: @WarpDriveEnterprises

AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'insert'

Comment: @Ayxan  expected output: 

[[4,7], [13,12]]

Comment: @mad_  i just tried adding a new element to an empty list , it is valid

Comment: Thanks for providing the extra information in the comments! You can improve your question by incorporating this information in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to create a list, which does not already exist. So, i want to use the insert function to insert "0" as the new element in that list.

You cannot insert to a non-existent list. You have to use `[]` to first create the list, then you can insert things into it.

**Solution**: On the line where you say `matrix_result.insert(i1, 0)`, you insert an `int` instead of a `list`. To insert an empty `list`, you have to say `matrix_result.insert(i1, [])`.

EDIT: As Jondiedoop has said, it is usually recommended to use the `numpy` library for matrix operations because it is highly optimized and easy to use. Go here for more information: [NumPy.org](http://www.numpy.org/)

Answer (score 3):

For all matrix manipulations, use the `numpy`-library:

```
import numpy as np
np.array(matrix1) + np.array(matrix2)
```

Output:

```
#array([[ 4,  7],
#      [13, 12]])
```

Apart from being much easier and much more flexible, it will also be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

Your empty list `matrix_result` presented a few challenges to the interpreter. I made a few changes to your code and the matrices add.

```
matrix1 = [[1, 5], [6, 4]]
matrix2 = [[3, 2], [7, 8]]
matrix_result = [[0,0], [0,0]] # CHANGE: empty array is now zeroes


def add_matrix(p1, p2):
    global matrix_result

    for i1 in range(0, len(p1)):
        for i2 in range(0, len(p1[i1])):
            matrix_result[i1][i2] = 0 # change: no .insert(), just assignment. you can (and probably should) remove this line.
            matrix_result[i1][i2] = p1[i1][i2] + p2[i1][i2]
    return matrix_result


print(add_matrix(matrix1, matrix2))
```

I hope this helps you!

Comment: You probably do not need this line ` matrix_result[i1][i2] = 0` if you have already initialize the matrix values as `matrix_result = [[0,0], [0,0]]`

Comment: @mad_ Yeah. In the original code, there was an attempt to put it to 0. I don't know if that was there for a feature later on, so I left it. I did comment that it can be removed, though.

Answer (score 0):

Change the matrix_result to contain list of lists. Also problem in your solution is you are accessing the int type saved in the list            `matrix_result[i1]` and trying to insert in the int type which is not possible using `insert(i2, 0)`

```
matrix1 = [[1, 5], [6, 4]]
matrix2 = [[3, 2], [7, 8]]
matrix_result = [[0,0],[0,0]]

def add1(p1, p2):
    global matrix_result

    for i1 in range(len(p1)):
            for i2 in range(len(p1[i1])):  
                matrix_result[i1][i2] = p1[i1][i2] + p2[i1][i2]
    return matrix_result
print(add1(matrix1, matrix2))
```

Although you do not necessarily need `insert()` here but if you really want to then below is the updated version of your code

```
matrix1 = [[1, 5], [6, 4]]
matrix2 = [[3, 2], [7, 8]]
matrix_result = [[],[]]


def add1(p1, p2):
    global matrix_result

    for i1 in range(0, len(p1)):

        for i2 in range(0, len(p1[i1])):
            matrix_result[i1].insert(i2,0)
            matrix_result[i1][i2] = p1[i1][i2] + p2[i1][i2]
    return matrix_result

print(add1(matrix1, matrix2))
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to use `insert()` here. An easier way would be to use [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip):

```
matrix1 = [[1, 5], [6, 4]]
matrix2 = [[3, 2], [7, 8]]

def add(*args):
    matrix_result = []

    for pair in zip(*args):
        inner = []
        for x, y in zip(*pair):
            inner.append(x + y)
        matrix_result.append(inner)

    return matrix_result

print(add(matrix1, matrix2))
# [[4, 7], [13, 12]]
```

You can also use a list comprehension:

```
def add(*args):
    return [[x + y for x, y in zip(*pair)] for pair in zip(*args)]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to implement matrix addition, I assume that you want the following behaviour:

```
# m1 = [[1, 5], [6, 4]]
# m2 = [[3, 2], [7, 8]]
# add(m1, m2) => [[4, 7], [13, 12]]
```

If you can't use any libraries, you could use zip and map, where we also assume that the dimensions of the matrices are the same of course:

```
def add(p1, p2):
  adder = lambda tuple: [tuple[0][i] + tuple[1][i] for i in range(len(tuple[1]))]
  return list(map(adder, zip(p1, p2)))

print(add(matrix1, matrix2))
# [[4, 7], [13, 12]]
```

The simplest and fastest would be to use numpy:

```
import numpy as np 

def add(p1, p2):
    return np.array(p1) + np.array(p2)
```